# Flag dialogue popup is stacked behind realtime-post-deleted-notification banners

Tags: bug, design, deleted-answers, popups, flag-dialog

There is a little bug that becomes visible when a page contains `realtime-post-deleted-notification` banners (that's the CSS classname of these red banners appearing on answers which just got deleted, see screenshot below) and you try to open the flag dialogue above them:

[image: 1]

Obviously, the dialogue appears below the banners, which it clearly should not do. It also has no input focus, trying to interact with the dialogue fails and either closes it (clicking outside of the red banners) or reloads the page (clicking on the red banners).

The cause for this is simply the z-index ordering in the site's CSS. Relevant CSS snippets:

```
.realtime-post-deleted-notification {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 100;
}

.popup {
    display: none;
    padding: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

So the fix for this minor bug would probably be to raise the z-index of the `popup` class to something greater than 100.