# "This post has been deleted" banner overlaps Close Vote Dialog

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, deleted-posts

If an answer is deleted while the close vote dialog is open on the parent question, the "This post has been deleted" banner overlaps the modal.  This also renders the dialog useless, as clicking on it will refresh the page.

[image: This post has been deleted banner]

---

Google Chrome Version 57.0.2987.98 (64-bit)

macOS Sierra Version 10.12.4 (16E195)

Comment: @Riker the answer was deleted, not the question.

Comment: Edited to make the example more explicit, Floern has it right.

Comment: [Same with the flag dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293318/164356) and [cross-site dupe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317632/559745)

Comment: @ShadowWizard already done.

Comment: You did cast a close vote, I saw the counter at 2 so assumed you're not familiar with the insta-OP-dupe-close. :-) (if you are familiar, why the close vote? It's pointless)

Comment: @ShadowWizard shhh!  Don't tell anyone I messed up!

Comment: Too late, it's right up there in the banner for all to see... ;)